# JavaScript: How can I schedule a task every two minutes in selenium webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver, webdriverjs

I want to test my web page: login in a web page, then click refresh button every 2 minutes but not close the browser window. This is my simplified code(omit some details).

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

driver.get('http://www.example.com');
// login, omit login code
setInterval(function () {
   driver.findElement({id: "refresh"}).click();
}, 2 * 60 * 1000);
```

I want to know how can I schedule a task every two minutes in selenium webdriverjs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make a cron job. Checkout this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron